# Why is this やって来た read やってくた？

Tags: words, kanji, readings

Seen in the manga きみとピコピコ　(第17話)

[image]

> 夏合宿と称して
>
> 旅館{りょかん}にやって来{く}た

Why does やって来た have reading やってくた? Is this a typo or the reading くた actually exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be a typo. やって来た is always read やってきた.

A wild guess is that up to some point it was やって[来]{く}る and changed at the last minute.